# How to loop through all the files in a directory in c # .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the files in folder and also in its subfolders.The following code does not get the files in its subfolder:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*ProfileHandler.cs");
```

Can anyone Please tell me how to implement this in c# .net?

Comment: I've always preferred the MSDN method of doing things.  At the bottom of [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) they provide a recursive example w/ a console program (C#).

Comment: @Panuvin - 
Note: The MSDN code is a little dangerous. For very large folder and subfolder content (many many files) you can get a StackOverflow exception (because of the recursive code)

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
string[] files = 
    Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, "*ProfileHandler.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

That last parameter affects exactly what you're referring to. Set it to **AllDirectories** to include every file including those in subfolders, or set it to **TopDirectoryOnly** if you only want to search in the directory given and not subfolders.

Refer to MDSN for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will infinite loop if there's a loop in your folder structure.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx

Comment: What is the purpose of the middle parameter?

Comment: It's called searchPattern and it's a filter by which files are selected. In this case it will select all files ending in "ProfileHandler.cs". Have a look at [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

try below code

```
Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*ProfileHandler.cs",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this page showing Deep Folder Copy, it uses recursive means to iterate throught the files and has some really nice tips, like filtering techniques etc.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/512208/Folder-Directory-Deep-Copy-including-sub-directori