# metadata Extractor library path access denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, metadata-extractor

I've found this .net library that can extract metadata from images and the example they gave is below however whatever path i put in just gives a path access to the path is denied error. I am running visual studio as an admin so that shouldn't be the issue

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var directories = MetadataExtractor.ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata("C:\\New folder");

            foreach (var directory in directories)
            {
                foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
                    Console.WriteLine($"[{directory.Name}] {tag.Name} = {tag.Description}");

                if (directory.HasError)
                {
                    foreach (var error in directory.Errors)
                        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {error}");
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to set path to file, not folder. I've try it like this

```
C:\\New folder\\maxresdefault.jpg
```

And it's works. Output:

```
[JPEG] Compression Type = Baseline
[JPEG] Data Precision = 8 bits
[JPEG] Image Height = 720 pixels
[JPEG] Image Width = 1280 pixels
[JPEG] Number of Components = 3
[JPEG] Component 1 = Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 2 horiz/2 vert
[JPEG] Component 2 = Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JPEG] Component 3 = Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JFIF] Version = 1.1
[JFIF] Resolution Units = inch
[JFIF] X Resolution = 96 dots
[JFIF] Y Resolution = 96 dots
[JFIF] Thumbnail Width Pixels = 0
[JFIF] Thumbnail Height Pixels = 0
[Exif IFD0] X Resolution = 96 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] Y Resolution = 96 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] Resolution Unit = Inch
[Exif IFD0] Software = paint.net 4.0.19
[File] File Name = maxresdefault.jpg
[File] File Size = 121177 bytes
[File] File Modified Date = Вт май 29 13:45:59 +03:00 2018
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Is there a way to make it go through all the files in a specific folder

Comment: yes, but it's another question. Rsponse, for example, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254339/how-to-loop-through-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c-net